# jQuery animate to left or right from variable

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I would like to make elements move to right or left with jquery animate, and directions are generated from array.

Here is my code:

```
var leftOrRight = ['left', 'right'];

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    $('.footer').append('<div class="romb"></div>');
}

$('.romb').each(function(){

    var position = Math.random()*350,
        direction = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2),
        goTo = leftOrRight[direction],
        options = {goTo : position, 'bottom' : Math.random()*350};
        //alert(goTo);
        $(this).animate(options, Math.random()*1000, 'easeInOutBack');

});
```

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wbag5wv3/

Problem: variable (left or right) is generated properly, but animate won't move to left or right.

If I enter left or right manually, animation works as it should.

What I'm missing?

Comment: you are not using the `direction` at all.

Comment: Here is where I use direction: `goTo = leftOrRight[direction],`

Comment: Explained that in detail in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

```
var position = Math.random()*350,
    direction = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2),
    goTo = leftOrRight[direction],
    options = {goTo : position, 'bottom' : Math.random()*350};
```

1. You have gotten the `left` or `right` string from the array alright when you do `direction = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)`, but you are not using that as a property. What you assign to `goTo` is is a string `left` or `right`, but when you pass to the `options` object, you are believing that it would use the value of that variable, but it won't. You are defining the `options` object with the property `goTo` which means nothing in CSS.
2. You are assigning `position` to the `goTo` property. Even if you were to fix the above problem, you are still not assigning the correct value. You mean to use `position` for `top` actually.

***Solution***:

Write your code like this:

```
var pos = Math.random()*350,
    direction = leftOrRight[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)],
    options = {};
options['top'] = pos;
options[direction] = Math.random()*100;
$(this).animate(options, Math.random()*1000, 'easeInOutBack');
```

See, when you assign a value to `options[direction]`, it will be assigned to the correct property based on `direction`. i.e. it will be either `options.left` or `options.right`.

***See a working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/wbag5wv3/2/***

---

### Important:

Also, note that the code in the fiddle (while it fixes your code) will still not work as expected. That is because you have to clear/reset the `left` property when your `direction` is `right`. And, similarly clear the `right` property when your `direction` is `left`. How to do that, is left to you as an exercise.

.

Answer (score 0):

JS: ( "direction" => "left or right" )

```
var leftOrRight = ['left', 'right'];

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    $('.footer').append('<div class="romb"></div>');
}

$('.romb').each(function(){

    var pos = Math.random()*350,
        direction = leftOrRight[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)],
        options = {left : pos, bottom : Math.random()*350};

    $(this).animate(options, Math.random()*1000, 'easeInOutBack');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this** **[Click Here to See the Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/wbag5wv3/3/)**

Just change your line

```
 options = {goTo : position, 'bottom' : Math.random()*350};
```

To

```
options = {left : Math.random()*350};
```

Modified Function

```
var leftOrRight = ['left', 'right'];

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    $('.footer').append('<div class="romb"></div>');
}

$('.romb').each(function(){

    var pos = Math.random()*350,
        direction = leftOrRight[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)],
        options = {left : Math.random()*350}; // UPDATED THIS LINE

    $(this).animate(options, Math.random()*1000, 'easeInOutBack');

});
```

**Working Demo [-Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/wbag5wv3/3/)**